# Screws stuck inside of Anchors, with shelving unit in between.

Tags: drywall, screws, shelving, stuck

[image]

I drilled the anchors into the wall and used the screws they came with. The screws wouldn't drill all the way in to lay flat against the shelf, so I tried removing the screws from the anchors and the anchors came with them . Now the screws are stuck inside the anchors with the shelf in between them and I can't get them apart. Any tips?

Comment: You need to keep the anchors from turning while you back out the screws.  Try wrapping a rag around the anchor to preserve it and then grabbing it with pliers.  Or just grab the anchor with pliers and if it gets damaged, toss it.  If you pre-drilled the anchor hole (which you're not supposed to do), the hole might have been too loose.  Otherwise, the screw may be too big for the anchor.  It doesn't normally take excessive force to drive the screw into the anchor.  Be cautious of reusing the same holes with the same size anchors.  If you can, patch those holes and relocate to good drywall.

Answer (score 7):

The type of plastic drywall anchor that you show on those screws can be removed by holding the anchor with a pair of pliers and then back out the screw with a philips screwdriver. After the plastic part has been removed toss it into the trash.

Note that that type of anchor is not suitable for hanging a wall shelf unless that shelf is a piddly small thing only intended to hold some small nick-knacks. Any other application should have the screws going directly into studs in the wall.

Comment: ... or at least a toggle-type anchor, which can carry a surprising amount of weight when used in sets.

Comment: Having lived in earthquake country I'll never trust something screwed into drywall.  Drywall is not structural.  It's chalk and paper, so even if we trust the magic tech behind it, it cant't hold any weight at a single point.

Answer (score 0):

If the anchor is stuck like that in the photo (with metal between screw head and anchor), and the anchor is plastic, you can melt the anchor away with a fire-starter wand. I just did it. I held the bracket over the waste basket in a well-ventilated area and moved the wand around to melt the anchor (paying special attention to the anchor head). After a few minutes, I went at it with needle-nosed pliers, and repeated the process. It took a few minutes, but I was able to peel it away easily. And it sure was easier than wrenching my wrists trying to unscrew something with a stripped head. Do not do this if any part of the bracket is wood. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As methods indicated by others, you shouldn't find it is difficult to separate the plastic anchor and the screw, actually hot water can loosen the bite too.

However, as both the surfaces of the plastic anchor and the drilled hole are relatively smooth, you will likely find it is difficult to unscrew without pull the entire assembly out of the wall, so how to increase the friction between the anchor and the hole is the key to eliminate the headaches.

There are a few ways to enhance the friction, my favorite method is to apply wood glue and wood dust mixture to the hole and the anchor and wait until it has dried.
Be patient, as it will take a while for the glue to dry completely.

If you are installing the shelve on drywalls, you may consider using other types of anchors that are more suitable for the task.